# Div Text's Color Changes when Printed

Tags: html, css, media-queries, media

I have a div with white text color.

[image]

Using css media queries.

```
@media print {
     .myid_print_duo_name
     {
         z-index: 2;
         position: absolute;
         left: 0px;
         top: 330px;    
         width: 303px;
         height: 28px;
         line-height: 28px;     
         text-align: center;    
         color: white !important; 
         font-weight: bold;
         font-size: 20px;
         font-family: "Times New Roman";     
     }

 }
```

My text looks like a little bit darker in my print preview.

[image]

I thought it was just ok, but then the printed result is really the same in my print preview. Why is it turning a little bit darker?

Comment: are you using same colour for all screen sizes ?

Comment: Try giving color in hexacode like color:#ffffff !important;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**MDN Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust): Adding this below rule will overwrite the user's printer property settings.

```
@media print {
  .myid_print_duo_name { /* Replace class_name with * to target all elements */
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
            color-adjust: exact; /* Non-Webkit Browsers */
  }
}
```

Comment: Dang. This was it. Firefox was overriding the printing defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Try this css, it may help you.

```
@media print {
     .myid_print_duo_name{ -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; color:#fff !important;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers have a property called `print-color-adjust`, which might darkening some colours and lightening others. Try adding these in your CSS:

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
        print-color-adjust: exact;
```

Taken from Smashing's website: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/08/tips-and-tricks-for-print-style-sheets/